# Is AppCompat libraries still neccessary?

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

With the number of users moving to 7+ android version, is AppCompat still necessary or can I use the new libraries instead. This is specially related to styling. I want to switch to the Material design library for styling. What i'm asking is, is it recommend to use the new Material design library versus AppCompat?

Comment: MaterialComponents is built on top of AppCompat, now styled AndroidX

Answer (score 0):

The [Material Design Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) are built on top of AppCompat, so while you may use Material styles in place of AppCompat, you still need AppCompat under the hood to provide a consistent base across all API levels. This also means you need to continue to extend `AppCompatActivity`, etc.